# "could not find the ISO /ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso"

Tags: installation, iso

I used Grub4Dos to install Ubuntu, but it gave me this information:

> Could not find the ISO \ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso

I'm sure I put the ISO file in a correct pattern (C:, FAT32), and the filename is properly typed.

After that, I tried wubi installation, but after rebooting it shows like this:

> Could not find the ISO \ubuntu\install\installation.iso

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

For wubi, the .iso needs to be in the same directory as wubi.exe . Alternately, if you simply download and run wubi.exe it will download the iso for you.

Not sure about Grub4Dos.

If you want to make a bootable USB, I advise unetbootin. Unetbootin is crossplatform.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/